Explain what the simplicity in this argument is based on
Other people have minds because it is the best explanation for other people's behavior because the existence of other minds is a simpler and more understandable explanation:
It does not make me special among other people.
It does not require two completely different explanations: one for my behavior and one for the behavior of other people.
It does not make confusing and incomprehensible explanations that say that other people behave as if they have minds, but in fact, for some reason, other people do not have minds, and their behavior is formed by some unknown processes, it is not known how and why.
Where does simplicity and clarity come from here?
Does it arise because we do not violate analogy and the principle of uniformity?
Here simplicity and comprehensibility arise because we preserve analogy and the principle of uniformity?
That is, simplicity and comprehensibility are based on the preservation of analogy and the principle of uniformity?
If we violate the principle of uniformity and analogy, will it turn out to be a more complicated and unclear explanation?
But since the principle of uniformity and analogy are unsuitable for justifying the existence of other minds, does it follow that the argument from inference to the best explanation is also unsuitable for justifying the existence of other minds?
Am I not understanding something?
thank you

"Where does simplicity and clarity come from here?"  Thin is the line that separates simplicity from a cop out...  Have you seen e.g. this: "Other Minds (SEP)"?  --  Understanding, like philosophy, is not simply a word game.  IMO, your question, as it presently stands, lacks motivation, focus, and work.

I believe that simplicity arises because we preserve the principle of uniformity and analogy. But I don't know if it's true.

It is not.  Counter-example: the empty statement is the simplest and it is always if just vacuously true, yet it explains (it adds) exactly nothing, i.e. it is not an explanation. --  Does that answer your question?  It certainly does not answer mine.  (IMO) you should clarify and focus your question, not try some more "logical sparring".  I won't add more.

Does this answer your question? Is it plausible to believe in the existence of other minds if all arguments have been criticized?

I want to know whether in my abductive argument (IBE) simplicity and clarity are based on the principle of uniformity and analogy (induction) or is it something else?

And please also explain if an abductive argument is built on an inductive argument, will it be an abductive argument or an inductive one?

See occams razor. Shit happens just get used to it and try not deny it. Unless you like endless roundabouts.

You observe that others behave similarly to you. The best explanation for their behavior is that they have a mind like yours.
What makes it the best explanation? Because it's the most ontologically parsimonious explanation, and would be favored by Ockham's razor.
Ockham's Razor doesn't work on quantitative parsimony (number of entities postulated), it work on qualitative parsimony (number of types of entity postulated). Apply Ockham's Razor to the problem of other minds, it works like this: You have two theories:

Your behavior is caused by conscious mind, and others' similar behaviors are caused by god controlling them.
You and others have minds, which is why you behave similarly to others.

Theory 2 requires us to postulate a new unknown phenomenon (like god is controlling their body) and we have to add new entity to our ontology. Whereas theory 1 minds doesn't change our ontology at all and thus is more parsimonious (conscious mind < conscious mind + god). So other things being equal, we should prefer theory 2 over 1.
You might be interested in this video on Ockham's Razor: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3BxxKE-NcRo&t=513s.
